# What are the contributions of ancient Indian astronomers in mapping of the solar system and galaxies?

Tags: planetary-science, history, mathematics, astronomy

In the history of astronomy we usually come up with the name of European astronomers like Kepler and Galileo. Earlier Indian astronomers, for example [Aryabhata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryabhata) and [Bhaskaracharya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bh%C4%81skara_II), are not usually mentioned although it was them that first proved that Earth moves round the Sun and also identified and named galaxies. Why it is thus?

Comment: This is an interesting question! I noticed that Bhaskaracharya was applying elements of differential calculus to the orbital motion of celestial bodies five centuries before Newton! I am wondering if History of Science and Mathematics stackexchange (https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place for this question. It's not that this is completely off topic here, but that the people who would know the answer are probably there.

Comment: See just for example [What was the historical context of the development of Taylor series?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/2495/3869) and  [Discovery of zero](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/402/discovery-of-zero) and [Why isn't Aryabhata more famous than Pythagoras?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/3082/3869).